# Style segmented control buttons on iPhone?

Tags: cocoa-touch

Is it possible to change the styling of iPhone native buttons? For example, I'd like to use a smaller font size for part of the button text, and larger for another - something like

```
<small>pick a</small><big>color</big>
```

I'd also like to use buttons that form a right-arrow shape instead of being rectangular. Something like:

```
---------------------------------
\ Color  \   Size    \    Shape  \
/        /           /           /
----------------------------------
```

Any of that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can do it easily.  You'll probably have to subclass [`UISegmentedControl`](https://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISegmentedControl_Class/Reference/UISegmentedControl.html) and override a bunch of methods.  To get differently sized fonts on the button text, you'll have to create several `UILabel`s as subviews and give each one the appropriate text and font size, and then lay them out.  To get the right-arrow shape, you'll need to override the `drawRect:` method to draw the control's background.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest option is to use Rounded Rect Buttons with custom images, unfortunately this will not meet your resizable text requirement (unless you have images for each size).

- Add a Rounded Rect Button to the View
- In the Inspector:
  -switch the Type to "Custom"
  -set Background to the image of your new button
  -place the text in "Title"

Be sure to use Background for you button image if you want to use the button's text property (Title)

Answer (score 0):

You could subclass a UIView and have several UIButtons stacked together. To have each button form a right-arrow shape you could just use a stretchable image and set the UIButtons background to this UImage:

```
UIImage* buttonImage =[[UIImage imageNamed:@"arrowImage.png"] 
       stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:5.0 topCapHeight:0.0];
```

Here is a good starting point: https://github.com/boctor/idev-recipes/tree/master/CustomSegmentedControls

I have played with this and modified so I can customize the width of each segment and some other tweaks, here is my fork: https://github.com/janfsd/idev-recipes/tree/master/CustomSegmentedControls

You could further customize one of these to accept text size parameter per button to fit your needs.